# Write file input for subprocess

Tags: python, file, subprocess

I need to call a routine inside a loop which takes a text file as input. Because I don't want to open and close the text file all the time I keep it open in the loop. For Example:

```
with open("test.txt",'r+') as w_file:

    w_file.write(str(0.8) + "\n" + str(0.2))
    subprocess.call(["cat","test.txt"]) #Here I want to call my routine
```

But the file is still in the old state. Why? And whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: Try `w_file.flush()` after your `write` line, but before the `subprocess.call` line.

Comment: unrelated: you could use `print()` function: `print(0.8, 0.2, sep="\n",file=w_file)` or string formatting: `w_file.write("{}\n{}".format(0.8, 0.2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to close the file after writing.
try:

```
with open("test.txt",'r+') as w_file:
    w_file.write(str(0.8) + "\n" + str(0.2))

subprocess.call(["cat","test.txt"]) #Here I want to call my routine
```

or without closing, flush the file

```
with open("test.txt",'r+') as w_file:
    w_file.write(str(0.8) + "\n" + str(0.2))
    w_file.flush()
    subprocess.call(["cat","test.txt"]) #Here I want to call my routine
```

Comment: use `w` mode instead of `r+` to overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
with open("test.txt",'r+') as w_file:
    w_file.write(str(0.8) + "\n" + str(0.2))
    w_file.flush()
    subprocess.call(["cat","test.txt"])
```

The method "flush" syncs the actual file referenced by the file-like object w_file with the contents still in memory, so when you reference the file by it's name (and not the w_file FLO), you see an up to date version.

Comment: Sorry I kept my window open for a while before posting my answer and didn't notice someone else had already answered. Please discard this one.